# Zsh - can not do backspace after new line

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I am using zsh(not oh my zsh). The back button works, but it only works on the same line. If I have a new line(like if I hit the up arrow and bring back the last command) the back button will not go to the previous line.

I am using the vim key bindings. Any ideas how to fix?

```
bindkey -v
bindkey '^R' history-incremental-search-backward
bindkey "^[[A" history-search-backward
bindkey -v '^?' backward-delete-char
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by the "Back" button. You're showing bindings for Ctrl-R, Up cursor and Ctrl-?. Ctrl-? could be produced by Backspace or Delete depending on your terminal.

What are you trying to achieve with the `-v` option in that last binding? You've already selected vi mode. To bind a key in the vi command-mode keymap, use `-a`.

So what you perhaps want is:

```
bindkey -a '^?' backward-delete-char
```

Backspace stopping at the beginning of a line is consistent with actual vi behaviour. Vim behaves more like the following:

```
bindkey -a '^?' backward-char
```